# Browse folders freely using python

Tags: python, operating-system

I already know how to open the file explorer using the `os` module in python:

```
import os
os.startfile('D:/TEMP')
```

I would like to now use the *same* file explorer to browse to another directory. Meaning I would like to browse Windows directories without having to touch my mouse (ew) or open gazillions of file explorers.

Can the `os` library accomplish this? or perhaps another library?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you're going for?

Comment: I would like to  browse folders graphically using python. I am using Spyder and this does not allow cd functionality propagating through the IDE's file explorer. The only viable alternative is to browse through Window's regular file explorer. This is why I am asking the question. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 0):

os.listdir(".") 
. means in that folder.
You can change . to any place like /, /root, /home